# How can I recursively include all JS/CSS files from a directory into a specified HTML file?

Tags: ruby, rake

Given an HTML page, is there a way to automatically insert `<script>` and `<style>` tags into it from a directory?  I'm basically trying to build a '[style guide](https://github.com/trulia/hologram-example)' of sorts, and the main HTML page needs to dynamically reference every JS/CSS file that developers will add to a directory, and there will be many.

To put it quite bluntly, I'm looking for a gem equivalent of the node [grunt-include-source](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-include-source) module.  This is because I've already got a Rakefile invoking certain gems, I'd like to keep it consistent if possible/reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the names of each file in a directory with a `foreach` function and put them in an array(for example x). then in another `foreach` function for as many strings in the array and do

```
include: x[I]
```

then you do

```
I++
```

so you will get the next string in the array. 
Like this the `foreach` function will include every file in the directory.

I know it isnt the best way but it worked for me.